# How to bind OData to mailTo button in sap ui5

Tags: forms, odata, sapui5, abap

I have a SAP UI5 Form with a button at the bottom that should sendthe Form to an emmil address.

The backend part is already ready, made with ABAP, so I already have the OData address.

I need now a button in ui5 to bind this oData.

This is what I have so far

controlle.js:

```
onInit: function () {
                this.getView().byId("html").setContent("<canvas id='signature-pad' width='100' height='80' class='signature-pad' style='border:1px' ></canvas>");
                var oModel = new JSONModel({
                    checkboxes: [""],
                    checkboxes2: [""],
                    checkboxes3: [""]
                });
                this.getView().setModel(oModel);

                 
                var mailToButton = new sap.m.Button({
                    text: "Send Email",
                    id: "mailTo",
                    oDataBinding: {
                      path: "/sap/opu/odata/JOHN/JOHN_FORMULAR_SRV/SendMail?Body='Test'&RecieverList='john.doe@hotmail.com'&Subject='TestSubject'",
                      success: function(data) {
                        var email = data.Email;
                        window.open("mailto:" + email);
                      },
                      error: function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                      }
                    }
                  });
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "_version": "1.3.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "id": "opensap.myapp",
        "type": "application",
        "title": "{{appTitle}}",
        "description": "{{appDescription}}",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.0.0"
        }
    },
    "sap.ui": {
        "_version": "1.3.0",
        "technology": "UI5",
        "deviceTypes": {
            "desktop": true,
            "tablet": true,
            "phone": true
        }
    },
    "dataSources": {
        "cuProxyRemote": {
            "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/JOHN/JOHN_FORMULAR_SRV/SendMail?Body='Test'&RecieverList='john.doe@hotmail.com'&Subject='TestSubject'",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
                "odataVersion": "2.0"
            }
        }
    },
    "sap.ui5": {
        "_version": "1.3.0",
        "rootView": {
            "viewName": "opensap.myapp.view.App",
            "type": "XML",
            "async": true,
            "id": "app"
        },
        "autoPrefixId": true,
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.34",
            "libs": {
                "sap.ui.core": {"minVersion": "1.34.0"},
                "sap.m": {"minVersion": "1.34.0"},
                "sap.ui.layout": {"minVersion": "1.34.0"}
            }
        },
        "cuProxy": {
            "dataSource": "cuProxyRemote"
        },
        "models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "settings": {
                    "bundleName": "opensap.myapp.i18n.i18n"
                }
            },
            "MyViewModel": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel"
             }
        },
        "resources": {
            "css": [
              {
                "uri": "css/style.css"
              }
            ]
          },
        "contentDensities": {
            "compact": true,
            "cozy": true
        }
    }
}
```

I tried binding it in the XML file like this

```
<Button value="{/mailTo}" text="Send" press="btnHandler" id="mailTo"></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler solution.

XML:

```
<Button text="Send" press="onSendEmail" id="mailTo"></Button>
```

controller.js add a new function like this:

```
onShareEmailPress: function () {
    var email = data.Email;
    window.open("mailto:" + email);
},
```

You need to get your email from your Backend though, you should bind the oData to a model on your view, so that you can access it easily within your controller. In that case you would get your email with a line similar to this one (replacing what is between <>):

```
 var email = this.getView().getModel(<yourModel>).getData().<pathOfYourData>.Email;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest.json you have decared a data source called `cuProxyRemote`. This data source doesn't point to the service but to a function import in your service.

Remove the function call:

```json
"uri": "/sap/opu/odata/JOHN/JOHN_FORMULAR_SRV/"
```

is enough and everything else (entities, $metadata etc) will be added by the framework.

You can and should use this datasource to create an OData model (also in the manifest.json)

```json
"models": {
    "i18n": {
        "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
        "settings": {
            "bundleName": "opensap.myapp.i18n.i18n"
        }
    },
    "MyViewModel": {
        "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel"
    },
    "backend": {
        "dataSource": "cuProxyRemote"
    }
},
```

This way there is model at all times in your app that is connected to your OData service.

Now to your button. Buttons don't have a `value`. It is not entirely clear to me what you mean with "bind button to OData".

What you can do is what @IcyBow suggested and implement a button handler

```xml
<Button text="Send" press=".onSendEmail" />
```

and in your handler you can call the function import of your OData service

```js
onSendEmail: function(oEvent) {
    const oDataModel = this.getView().getModel("backend");
    oDataModel.callFunction("/SendMail", {
        urlParameters: {
            "Body": "Test",
            "Subject": "Test",
            "RecieverList": "john.doe@hotmail.com"
        },      
        sucess: (oData, response) => { /* called if successful */ },
        error: (oError) => { /* called if error */ }
    });
}
```

Ideally you would fill the body, subject and receiver list dynamically.